# Generate Casandra CQL queries dynamically

Tags: cassandra, cql

What is the equivalent of "1=1" for true condition in Cassandra CQL. I am trying to generate where clause in CQL query dynamically. But I am not able to use "1=1" truth condition for generating query dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#select) each predicate in WHERE clause must include column name:

```
select_statement ::=  SELECT [ JSON | DISTINCT ] ( select_clause | '*' )
                      FROM table_name
                      [ WHERE where_clause ]
...
where_clause     ::=  relation ( AND relation )*
relation         ::=  column_name operator term
                      '(' column_name ( ',' column_name )* ')' operator 
...
```

So I don't see any way around it.

My understanding is that you need to omit WHERE clause when you need the true condition, i.e., everything is returned.

Comment: Yes. I need truth condition so that I don't need to check if any where condition is present while generating where clause. As I always have where condition with this truth condition and add any condition if required dynamically.

Comment: @Mohan I suggest you to redesign your solution, since the only way to get true condition is to not have WHERE clause at all.

Answer (score 2):

In cass, the where clauses are always on keys. Cass does not see 1 as a key.